# Change PubSub subscription with redis-py

Tags: python, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe, gevent

I have a real-time webapp where a client receives updates from multiple Redis PubSub channels, built with gevent-socketio and redis-py.

I'm looking at the [views.py, l.26](https://github.com/sontek/django-tictactoe/blob/master/tictactoe/apps/core/views.py#L26) in the [django-tictactoe](https://github.com/sontek/django-tictactoe) example. 
It spawns a new greenlet when the client sends a subscribe message for a channel. The greenlet then subscribes to the Redis PubSub channel and blocks until a message is received.

```
class GameNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    def listener(self, chan):
            red = redis.StrictRedis(REDIS_HOST)
            red = red.pubsub()
            red.subscribe(chan)

            print 'subscribed on chan ', chan

            while True:
                for i in red.listen():
                    self.send({'message': i}, json=True)

    def recv_message(self, message):
        action, pk = message.split(':')

        if action == 'subscribe':
            Greenlet.spawn(self.listener, pk)
```

From my understanding, it is not possible to add subscriptions without spawning new Greenlets or unsubscribe from subscriptions.

How would you handle frequent subscriptions and unsubscriptions in an efficient way?

**Update:** What I'm building is a HTML5 realtime MMO game on a theoretically infinite 2D-map. Due to the size of the map, it is impossible to send the state of the whole map to the browser. The map is therefor partitioned in tiles which are loaded dynamically as the player drags the map (think Google Maps).

Whenever the maps is dragged, the client/browser subscribes to updates for the tiles which just became visible and, after a short delay, unsubscribes from updates on tiles that became invisible. Changes to subscription should happen maybe once per second per player, so *frequent* is relative.

The number of clients will (hopefully) be large. Theoretically, all players could look at the same part of the map, making [SUBSCRIBE](http://redis.io/commands/subscribe) and [UNSUBSCRIBE](http://redis.io/commands/unsubscribe) very expensive, as they are "`O(N) where N is the number of clients already subscribed to a channel`". In practice, it will be evenly spread over the world, so this should not be a problem.

However, **my main issue is that the Python Redis PubSub implementation blocks on listen.** Once I call red.listen() in the example above, I can't change the subscription anymore until a message arrives. The example code above starts a new Greenlet with a new connection to Redis per subscription, which is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the partitioning rationale/requirement is across subscriptions, i.e. what information flows across the subscriptions that must be kept separate from other subscriptions, so it's hard to answer definitively.  I'll go with some assumptions...

If you have a small or fixed number of clients managing multiple subscriptions, it might be better to multiplex a number of different events through a single long-lived subscription, with that Redis client doing the demultiplexing to the eventual event consumers.  This approach would likely be more performant from a Redis perspective than to repeatedly set up and tear down a subscription for each consumer.

Schemes like this require some additional intelligence on the part of the publishers so they can select the right queue for each message, but that can sometimes be easy to achieve, e.g. by hashing a client ID modulo N, where N is the number of pub/sub queues.

I hope this has something to do with what you were asking about...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is only partially related to my problem, but your advice will probably be valuable in the future. Right now, I'm not so much concerned with Redis performance, but with proper usage of the Python Redis client. I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I use Redis with C#/Booksleeve (written by SO's own @MarkGravell, kudos), so I don't know much about the Python library.  But I suspect that its blocking design is a hint that most people don't use it the way you're describing, and when that happens to me my spidey-sense goes off that maybe I should look at the problem differently.  In this case I wonder if it wouldn't be better to have each client use a single non-Redis connection to a proxy/management service that manages the user's view/subscriptions for them, allowing you to easily try out different strategies, even at runtime.